# Do I need to test if .vim/autoload/plug.vim exists before running it?

Tags: vim, autoload

Do I need to test if .vim/autoload/plug.vim exists before running it?

I'm studying the vimrc generate by https://vim-bootstrap.com/ and in one one the first lines it has:

```
let vimplug_exists = expand('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim')
if !filereadable(vimplug_exists)
  if !executable("curl")
    echoerr "You have to install curl or first install vim-plug yourself!"
    execute "q!"
  endif
  echo "Installing Vim-Plug..."
  echo ""
  silent !\curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  " let g:not_finish_vimplug = "yes"

  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall
endif

" Required:
call plug#begin(expand('~/.vim/plugged'))
...
```

And then a lot of `Plug '.../...'`. What would be a purpose of that? Also, I don't understand what is `autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall` doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `vimrc` file is using [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) to manage plugins.

Quick overview of vim-plug:

- Use `Plug {github-user}/{repo}` to use the specified plugin repository
- `Plug` statement should be between `call plug#begin()` and `call plug#end()`
- `plug#begin({dir})` can specify directory, `{dir}`, where vim-plug controlled plugins will live
- `:PlugInstall` will do any necessary fetching & installing of all defined plugins
- `if executable('curl')` check to make sure you have an executable `curl` program. This is used to download vim-plug

Much of this code is to make sure vim-plug is present and tries to install itself.

#### Opinion: Avoiding Vim distributions

Personally, I feel like vim-bootstrap is a Vim distribution. I must warn you, it is very compelling to jump into Vim with a bunch of plugins and a customized `vimrc` file. However, I would advise you to avoid distributions and customized `vimrc` files. These distributions often make it feel like a different editor or sell you on the idea of these "must have" plugins. Often this causes newer Vim users to get confused where vanilla Vim ends and their plugins begin. When it comes to customizing Vim newer Vimmers often do not have the prerequisite knowledge needed to understand and maintain their distribution's `vimrc` setup.  Instead I suggest slowly learning and building your own `vimrc`. Basically "sharpen the saw"

---

### Repost of [Learning Vim after vimtutor](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4119/778):

#### Sharpen the saw

The best general advice is a simple one, "[Sharpen the saw](http://www.moolenaar.net/habits.html)" from Bram's Seven habits essay. I also suggest [Vimcasts blog](http://vimcasts.org/) post: [On sharpening the saw](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2012/08/on-sharpening-the-saw/).

Basically "sharpening the saw" can be summarized as:

> Don't learn everything all at once, but learn a few things at a time.
>   When you find an inefficiency look for ways to improve it. Repeat

#### Vimrc

I also recommend you use [nearly blank vimrc](https://github.com/romainl/idiomatic-vimrc). You should roughly understand each line in your `vimrc`. Use `:help` and google learn more.

#### Plugins

General plugin advice:

- Slowly add a plugin or two when the need arises.
- Do not install a plugin without looking for a native solution first
- Must have good documentation
- Avoid plugins with many mappings
- If it doesn't feel Vim-like then avoid it
- Avoid if mappings doesn't work with the `.` command (may have to use [repeat.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat))

#### More good places to learn more about Vim

- [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) - Great articles and screencasts by Drew Neil, the author of *Practical Vim*.
- [Derek Wyatt's Vim Videos](http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/) - Good collection of Vim topics.
- [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) - Steve Losh teaches how to customize Vim from the basics to the more advanced.

#### TL;DR

Read `:help` and try to make small incremental changes to your workflow.